# Can't change the src of un image in javascript in django

Tags: javascript, django

So I have a javascript file that I try change the src of a image with in django. However, it keeps adding a subdirectory called the directory my image is in (the directory being in the static folder). It looks like this:

```
Root/
   Project/
     Templates/
        games/
           game-one.html
     static/
         pre-dev/
            behav.js
            seven.png
```

in my javascript file because i cant use django tags I wrote it like this:
`document.getElementById('img_eight').src = "static/pre-dev/seven.png"`

and the image adress then looks like this:
`https://website.com/pre-dev/static/pre-dev/seven.png`

I would like to keep it as a js file, and I want to keep my images where they are

I have tried moving my behav.js a directory down. but it gives me the same output.

no matter what I change the src in my javascript file to I always get /pre-dev/.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Seems like it automatically sets the `/pre-dev/` part in the url, so just change src to `seven.png`. That way you should be able to access the image, since it is in the pre-dev directory.

Comment: I've tried that but, the URL I need is /static/pre-dev/. and it won't let me put anything before /pre-dev/

Comment: So, that didn't work? Why do you need `static/pre-dev/`? Doesn't the static just indicate, that the files and directories within it are directly accessible throught the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my experience in Javascritp when dealing with urls you have **two ways** of writing it

```
document.getElementById('img_eight').src = "/static/pre-dev/seven.png"
```

or

```
document.getElementById('img_eight').src = "static/pre-dev/seven.png"
```

notice the different here is the `/`

the second method (the one you wrote) will create a url with the current window url
like `www.example.com/current_endpoint/static/pre-dev/seven.png`
but if you add a `/` in the beginning you will get only the domain name without the endpoint

```
www.example.com/static/pre-dev/seven.png
```

another way to improve this and make it more dynamic is to use an empty div to get data

```
<div id='my_image_url' data-img-url="{{ your_context.image_url}}"></div>
```

hope that helps